# SwiftUI: How to center multi column picker on screen

Tags: swiftui, picker

I created a multi column picker with SwiftUI that I want to center on the screen.
However, whatever I try it remains left outlined as shows on the picture.

What I've tried:

- Adding (alignment: .center) on the GeometryReader, HStack and VStack.
- Trying to center the picker itself
- putting the pickers in a container and center that

So the question is how do center the 3 columned picker on the screen.
Thanks for your support!

Paul

[image: demo]

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var initial = "n"
    @State var final = "iu"
    @State var tone = 2
    @State var pinyin = ""
    
    var initials = ["b","c","ch","d","f","g","h","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","sh","t","w","x","z","zh"]
    var finals = ["a","ai","an","ang","ao","e","ei","en","eng","er","i","ia","ian","iang","iao","ie","in","iong","iu","o","ong","u","ua","uan","uang","uai","ui","un","uo","ü","üan","üe","ün"]
    var tones = [Int](1..<6)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Text("你")
                .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                HStack{
                    
                    Picker(selection: self.$initial, label: Text("")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.initials.count) { index in
                            Text("\(self.initials[index])").tag(self.initials[index])
                        }
                    }
                    .onReceive(Just(initial), perform: { value in
                        updatePinyin()
                    })
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/6, height: 200).clipped()
                    
                    Picker(selection: self.$final, label: Text("")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.finals.count) { index in
                            Text("\(self.finals[index])").tag(self.finals[index])
                        }
                    }
                    .onReceive(Just(final), perform: { value in
                        updatePinyin()
                    })
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/6, height: 200).clipped()
                    
                    Picker(selection: self.$tone, label: Text("")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.tones.count) { index in
                            Text("\(self.tones[index])").tag(self.tones[index])
                        }
                    }
                    .onReceive(Just(tone), perform: { value in
                        updatePinyin()
                    })
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/6, height: 200).clipped()
                }
            }
            
            Text(pinyin)
            
        }
    }
    
    func updatePinyin() {
        
        pinyin = initial + final + String(tone+1)
        print(pinyin)
        
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure the final goal, but for provided code it can be done just by making `Stack` consume all space provided by `GeometryReader`, like

```
HStack{
 
  // ... other code here 

}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)     // << this one !!
```

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Just add spacer in both side of `Picker`(s), Like that,

```
  HStack { 
       Spacer()
       // Other Codes
       Spacer()
  }
```